# Publish website to Azure, remove additional files at destination, but ignore specific folders

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-web-app-service, publish

I currently manually delete obsolete folders from a published azure website. I know there is an option in visual studio to `Remove additional files at destination`. My problem is that I have an Images folder (quite large) that users upload, that will be deleted when I publish with this option checked. My question is, is there a way to use this option with exclusions? Meaning, to delete all files that are not in the local project except "\Images" folder?

Comment: Why are you storing user uploaded data on Azure websites? There is no guarantee on the data being retained in case of a crash/machine failure. Azure storage should be used for the same.

Comment: @AbhaySaraf That's not entirely accurate; Azure Web Apps have storage that's durable (until the web app itself is deleted).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thank you. I did some research and it seems everything under d:\home is stored on Azure storage and [persisted as documented here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment).

Answer (score 2):

You can most likely customize the web deploy usage from VS to do what you want but I don't think I would recommend it since things like that tend to get fragile.

I would suggest changing your architecture to store the images in a blob container, then possibly mapping your blobs to a custom domain (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-custom-domain-name/).

Having your images in blob storage will also prevent any accidental deletion of the Images folder by someone else that doesn't know it shouldn't be touched (or you simply forgetting about it one day).

Using blob storage will also allow you to configure CDN usage if ever find that you needed it.

Another option would be to create a virtual directory on your WebApp configuration and put the Images there - that way your VS deploy/publish wouldn't be modifying that subdirectory.  This link may help with that: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/